# Small Windows 7 on Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I am using MacBook Air 13".
I need to install Windows 7 on my MB to run some software.
I have about 30GB free space on my MB.
Is there any Windows 7 distribution that uses less space and works with Bootcamp?

Comment: If you're only needing Windows to run some software, why not use something like Wine?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Microsoft editions of Windows are all the same size, the feature sets are unlocked by what edition you've paid for.

- professional
- enterprise
- home and business
- student
- ultimate

All of them take up the same amount of space, but some have limited access to features.

---

I would install the windows partition to an external drive.
You **might** be able to squeak by with 30GB if you have less than 4GB of windows files.